# Database storing: pure or encoded?

Tags: database, storing-data, storing-information

A simple question. How should I store telephone numbers and e-mail adresses in a database ? Just pure text (or numbers) like email@email.com or is it better to encode it with a key (a bit like how passwords are saved in databases). In that case it becomes unreadable (and much longer) unless you know the key.

The only reason for that would be if someone hacks the databsae, and let's say they are many important e-mails and telephone numbers in the database.

How does, for example, linkedIn and facebook keep all this data?

Comment: +1 for considering keeping sensitive data safe.

Answer (score 0):

Telephone numbers are semi-unique Id's.   They are not numeric quantities or counts.  They can be digits and in some cases  alphanumeric, e g. 1-(800)-flowers.

Store the telephone numbers as text as you don't want to add,  subtract, multiply or divide them. You can normalize the numbers into county code, and area code and number if there is a need to  search by country or area code. An alternative is to provide a functions to access the a telephone number text string and derive the county code and area code.

Another important aspect do you store the format codes ( parens, spaces  symbol, or dashes)  for the numbers '(123) 456-7890' or do you strip these out and  store only digits. If you want to have semi-uniqueness or  be able to search for equality then just store the digits.  Some numbers are
special  codes like '*82'  do want to allow  these as number as well?

I you wish  to derive any intelligence from the telephone number then you should base the number's structure   on the text fields based on the North American Numbering Plan  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan.